# Web3: Sending a signed serialized transaction throws an error: rlp: expected input list for types.txdata. Please help

Tags: web3js, rlp

I am feeding a signed serialized raw transaction to sendRawTransaction of web3. The problem is that whenever I call sendRawTransaction it throws an error:

```
rlp: expected input list for types.txdata.
```

I have read stuffs about RLP but I can't seem to fully understand it. I am using web3@0.20.6 because we cannot use the beta version just yet. Help is very much appreciated thank you!!

Comment: How do you sign the transaction? Try decoding the raw transaction with a decoder https://blockchains.tools/rawTransactionDecoder?l=ETH, if that fails it is likely you are not generating it properly.

Comment: I am using azure keyvault to sign transactions. I found out that my signature was indeed correct however there was no context of the actual transactions within the signature. Now that I've assembled the transaction before signing it, it now works.
Thanks for the response I really appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps explaining your situation as an answer will help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error `rlp: expected input list for types.txdata` happens when your signed raw tx is invalid. If you put the tx hex into an Ethereum tx decoder it will be invalid.

My best guess is that the EIP-1559 fee parameters `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` are not supported. Fix by replacing them with `gas` and `gasPrice`.

Same problem as this Q: [EIP-1559: Why does geth expect an input list for types.txdata?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119252/eip-1559-why-does-geth-expect-an-input-list-for-types-txdata/139944#139944)