# EIP-1559: Why does geth expect an input list for types.txdata?

Tags: raw-transaction, encoding, sendrawtransaction, rlp, eip-1559

I manually composed, signed, and serialized the following raw transaction:

```
02f87282053980018504a817c800825208940c512b60531e2440edbee50f48bafdc6d291d8dd890246ddf9797668000080c080a075488ef7d2d6192758545f0020dd3e381a610068e6e7539860461ca25a952d38a0377b07f01be37bc1ebb48eb1ec9fa62c8e4ebf5c6b03d31a113b964b8c9e37e9
```

It is a type-2 transaction consisting of the type-prefix byte and the RLP-encoded and signed transaction as per EIP-1559.

However, sending it to Geth gives me the following error:

```
eth.sendRawTransaction("0x02f87282053980018504a817c800825208940c512b60531e2440edbee50f48bafdc6d291d8dd890246ddf9797668000080c080a075488ef7d2d6192758545f0020dd3e381a610068e6e7539860461ca25a952d38a0377b07f01be37bc1ebb48eb1ec9fa62c8e4ebf5c6b03d31a113b964b8c9e37e9")
Error: rlp: expected input list for types.txdata
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:23(4)
```

The transaction is a simple value transfer without any call data or any access list. However, it seems to expect some kind of list. My RLP-decoder manages to read the transaction as follows:

```ruby
Eth::Tx.decode "02f87282053980018504a817c800825208940c512b60531e2440edbee50f48bafdc6d291d8dd890246ddf9797668000080c080a075488ef7d2d6192758545f0020dd3e381a610068e6e7539860461ca25a952d38a0377b07f01be37bc1ebb48eb1ec9fa62c8e4ebf5c6b03d31a113b964b8c9e37e9"
=> #<Eth::Tx::Eip1559:0x000056001ab1ab00
 @access_list=[],
 @amount=42000000000000000000,
 @chain_id=1337,
 @destination="0c512b60531e2440edbee50f48bafdc6d291d8dd",
 @gas_limit=21000,
 @max_fee_per_gas=20000000000,
 @max_priority_fee_per_gas=1,
 @payload="",
 @sender="61792A47cA5D231d0a8c165536586f83DC893C12",
 @signature_r="75488ef7d2d6192758545f0020dd3e381a610068e6e7539860461ca25a952d38",
 @signature_s="377b07f01be37bc1ebb48eb1ec9fa62c8e4ebf5c6b03d31a113b964b8c9e37e9",
 @signature_y_parity=0,
 @signer_nonce=0,
 @type=2>
```

But geth fails to decode the transaction. So I would assume there is a bug in my transaction composer or rlp-encoder. But I literally cannot see it. The following transaction decoders also fail:

- https://live.blockcypher.com/eth/decodetx/
- https://www.ethereumdecoder.com/
- https://flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx/

This is what I manually decoded:

```ruby
02                           # eip-1559 transaction tpye
f872                         # rlp-prefix (list of 12?)
     82 0539                 # chain id (1337)
     80                      # nonce (0)
        01                   # priority fee (1)
     85 04a817c800           # max fee (20 gwei)
     82 5208                 # gas limit (21_000)
     94 0c512b60531e2440edbee50f48bafdc6d291d8dd # destination
     89 0246ddf97976680000   # amount (42 ether)
     80                      # data (empty "")
     c0                      # access list (empty [])
     80                      # y-parity (0)
     a0 75488ef7d2d6192758545f0020dd3e381a610068e6e7539860461ca25a952d38 # r
     a0 377b07f01be37bc1ebb48eb1ec9fa62c8e4ebf5c6b03d31a113b964b8c9e37e9 # s
```

Where is the bug? Is an empty access list supposed to be `80` or `c0`?

Maybe related: [How to encode empty transaction fields?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117384/how-to-encode-empty-transaction-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after manually debugging the RLP for an hour, it turned out that I was running a Geth version that did not support EIP-1559 yet. :facepalm:

```
INFO [01-18|16:50:33.830] Wrote custom genesis block OK            config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 ConstantinopleFix: 0 Istanbul: 0 MuirGlacier: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [01-18|16:50:33.830] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 ConstantinopleFix: 0 Istanbul: 0 MuirGlacier: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [01-18|16:50:33.830] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[65 64 63]" network=1337 dbversion=<nil>
WARN [01-18|16:50:33.830] Upgrade blockchain database version      from=<nil> to=8
```

Upgrading to v1.10.15 fixed it.

```
INFO [01-18|17:53:30.506] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: 0, Berlin: 0, London: 0, Arrow Glacier: <nil>, MergeFork: <nil>, Engine: clique}"
INFO [01-18|17:53:30.506] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1337 dbversion=<nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `rlp: expected input list for types.txdata` happens when your signed raw tx is invalid. If you put the tx hex into an Ethereum tx decoder it will be invalid.

In this case, the EIP-1559 fee parameters `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` are not supported. Fix by replacing them with `gas` and `gasPrice`.